# Hide Tab Bar item and use its view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

In order to explain better what I am trying to achieve I provide you photo below. On my application I have navigation bar and tab bar. On tab bar I want to have only 4 items but also I need some hidden item. I want to use that hidden item to show some data and want my tab bar with constant 4 items always available, together with navigation bar of course. On this hidden item I want to show data according to link item clicked on my menu.

[image: Blue navigation controller with connected view controller have to be hidden]

**Edit:**

On second photo below you can see expanded menu. When I click on for example "iPhone 5s" menu item, I want to open view controller (VC5, green vc on first photo from below).I manage to open this tab with code:

`ContainerVC.tabBarViewController?.selectedIndex = 0`

After Gereons suggestion I put these lines of code into VC5 (on viewDidLoad function):

`let vc5 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC5")!`
    `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc5, animated: true)`

These lines of code actually displays VC5 controller on the way I wanted. VC5 is pushed on controller connected to first tab bar item.

Problems:

- back button on VC5 works only for first time and then it is not possible to access it over "iPhone 5s" menu item. It seems that viewDidLoad function runs only once.
- first tab bar item is intended to be shortcut to home page if someone click on tab bar item but also to display other view controllers such as VC5 when someone click on one of menu items. On this way I will have all functionalities I want but without hiding one of tab bar items because it seems that is not possible at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why does the 5th view controller be hidden? Can't you simply create and push it to the navigation stack when needed?

Comment: If that is possible, why not. Everything i want is to keep only 4 and fixed tab bar items and on navigation bar just menu item or back item. If you have some example please show me

Answer (score 0):

You can change `viewControllers` property of `UITabBarController`, to hide or show a view controller as you want.

Suppose I have 3 VCs connected in tabBarController in IB; to hide the third do this:

```
class customTabBar : UITabBarController
{
   override func awakeFromNib()
   {  
      let vc1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc1ID")               

      let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc2ID")

      let vc3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc3ID") // I will hide this

      self.viewControllers = [VC1,VC2]

   }
```

Also put storyboardID to your hidden VC and load it anyware

Edit: you can have awakeFromNib without connections on IB , or you can process viewControllers array in awakeFromNib and remove the one at the index you want with all connections set in IB.

You hide a view Controller from tabBar by assigning array of vcs (all connected ones except one you want to hide ) to tabBarController's viewControllers property, you access a viewController by setting a storyboardID to it in IB

```
  let loadHiddenVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "hidenID")
```

present or push loadHiddenVC  as you like

Comment: My tab bar controller have its own class. How to call VC1 and VC2 on that class if they are storyboardIDs of mentioned view controllers

Comment: After your edit I am confused a little bit,  do I still need to have awakeFromNib func? On IB I am already connected VCs even that one I want to hide.

Comment: you can have awakeFromNib without connections on IB , or you can process viewControllers array in awakeFromNib and remove the one at the index you want with all connections set in IB

Comment: Actually that is the point of my question, how to remove tab bar item but still use its view controller. When I try with awakeFromNib I still have all tab bar items

Comment: i did everything like you said. I created new viewController which is not connected to tab bar (I did this using IB). Then I set storyboard ID to this vc called VC5. After that when I instantiate this vc, add it to tab bar and present. Code for this is:
 `let vc3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC5") 
            self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = [vc3!]
            self.present(vc3!, animated: true, completion: nil)'`. The problem with this is way of presenting. VC5 view controller opens on full screen and hover navigation and tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

I would not mess with the tabbar, but instead create the 5th view controller as needed (possibly from a different storyboard file) and push it on the navigation stack:

```
func displayFifthViewController() {
    let vc5 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC5")!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc5, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I have only one storyboard, everything is like on photo

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your usage better.

Comment: I tried your solution and it opens VC5 but inside burger menu. I need to open it on view controller with navigation bar and tab bar included. That is why I am trying to hide one of tab bar item, inside that item I want to show table view with different kind of data, according to chosen menu item.

Comment: What's the "burger menu"? You said you were using a tab bar (bottom) and navigation bar (top).

Comment: Just forgot burger menu, call it just menu. Generally on my app I am using menu, and on every view I have navigation bar and tab bar. Later on I will update my question with more details about general idea. It seems that nobody can understand what i am trying to achieve with hidden tab bar item.

Comment: Gareon, please check my edit. This edit is actually mix of your and Sh_Khan recommendations.